# Finding the next XML element

Tags: javascript, parsing, xml, iterator, iteration

I am looking for a better way to do a `while` cycle with the variable update.

The background is that I'm writing a StAX-line XML reader in JavaScript and want to implement a `skipElement` function. The function may only be called on the start tag and should skip everything until the closing end tag.

- `this.nextTag()` skips to the next tag and returns `Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT` or `Jsonix.XML.Input.END_ELEMENT` depending on whether it is a start or an end tag.
- `numberOfOpenTags` holds the number of open tags, increased/decreased accordingly.
- If we have a closing tag and `numberOfOpenTags` is `1`, we're done.

```
skipElement : function() {
    if (this.eventType !== Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT) {
        throw new Error("Parser must be on START_ELEMENT to skip element.");
    }
    // We have one open tag at the start
    var numberOfOpenTags = 1;
    // Skip to the next tag
    var et = this.nextTag();
    // If we have an END_ELEMENT and there is exactly one tag still open, we're done
    while (et !== Jsonix.XML.Input.END_ELEMENT || numberOfOpenTags !== 1)
    {
        if (et === Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT)
        {
            numberOfOpenTags++;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfOpenTags--;
        }
        et = this.nextTag();
    }
    return et;
}
```

I am looking for improvements. What I don't like:

- `this.nextTag()` is called on two occasions.
- Another check for `et` within the cycle: `if (et === Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT)`.
- Too verbose `if`/`else` in the cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about don't go to the next element before the loop, just check for the counter to reach zero, get the next element first in the loop, and the use a conditional operator to determine how to change the counter:

```
skipElement : function() {
  if (this.eventType !== Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT) {
    throw new Error("Parser must be on START_ELEMENT to skip element.");
  }
  var numberOfOpenTags = 1;
  var et;
  while (numberOfOpenTags > 0) {
    et = this.nextTag();
    numberOfOpenTags += et === Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT ? 1 : -1;
  }
  return et;
}
```

Comment: Probably `var et = this.eventType;` is missing?

Comment: @lexicore: Yes, you are right. However, I rewrote the code so that it returns the same element as the original code.

Comment: Cool. I just added brackets around `(et === Jsonix.XML.Input.START_ELEMENT)`.

Comment: @lexicore: That's not needed as the comparison has the highest precedence here, but you might want it for readability.

Comment: Correct, this was only for readability purposes.